# Latest localstack does not start Dynamodb properly in Linux

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, mocking, amazon-dynamodb, localstack

I have below versions of

```
python --> 3.6.10
pip --> pip 19.3.1 from python2
localstack --> 0.11.1
Docker --> 18.09.9-ce
```

but when I tried to start the localstack -->`localstack start`

it throws me below error:

```
LocalStack version: 0.11.1.1
Starting local dev environment. CTRL-C to quit.
docker run -it -e DEFAULT_REGION="us-east-1" -e TEST_AWS_ACCOUNT_ID="000000000000" -e HOSTNAME="10-20-134-45" -e LOCALSTACK_HOSTNAME="10-20-134-45" --rm --privileged --name localstack_main -p 8080-8081:8080-8081 -p 4567-4620:4567-4620 -p 10000:10000  -v "/tmp/localstack:/tmp/localstack" -v "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock" -e DOCKER_HOST="unix:///var/run/docker.sock" -e HOST_TMP_FOLDER="/tmp/localstack" "localstack/localstack"
Unable to find image 'localstack/localstack:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from localstack/localstack
5a20acb0595b: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:78e3bce5360fc42890d3e1cc16fac660b32a4a29d0c7f0068ff52d18458dbb19
Status: Downloaded newer image for localstack/localstack:latest
Waiting for all LocalStack services to be ready
2020-05-18 16:55:22,958 CRIT Supervisor is running as root.  Privileges were not dropped because no user is specified in the config file.  If you intend to run as root, you can set user=root in the config file to avoid this message.
2020-05-18 16:55:22,961 INFO supervisord started with pid 13
2020-05-18 16:55:23,963 INFO spawned: 'dashboard' with pid 19
2020-05-18 16:55:23,965 INFO spawned: 'infra' with pid 20
2020-05-18 16:55:23,971 INFO success: dashboard entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 0 seconds (startsecs)
(. .venv/bin/activate; bin/localstack web)
LocalStack version: 0.11.1
(. .venv/bin/activate; exec bin/localstack start --host)
LocalStack version: 0.11.1
Starting local dev environment. CTRL-C to quit.
2020-05-18 16:55:25,555 INFO success: infra entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
Waiting for all LocalStack services to be ready
Starting edge router (https port 4566)...
Starting mock API Gateway service in http ports 4566 (recommended) and 4567 (deprecated)...
2020-05-18T16:55:30:INFO:localstack.multiserver: Starting multi API server process on port 51492
Starting mock CloudFormation service in http ports 4566 (recommended) and 4581 (deprecated)...
Starting mock CloudWatch service in http ports 4566 (recommended) and 4582 (deprecated)...
Starting mock DynamoDB service in http ports 4566 (recommended) and 4569 (deprecated)...
Starting mock DynamoDB Streams service in http ports 4566 (recommended) and 4570 (deprecated)...
Starting mock EC2 service in http ports 4566 (recommended) and 4597 (deprecated)...
Starting mock ES service in http ports 4566 (recommended) and 4578 (deprecated)...
Starting mock Firehose service in http ports 4566 (recommended) and 4573 (deprecated)...
Starting mock IAM service in http ports 4566 (recommended) and 4593 (deprecated)...
Starting mock STS service in http ports 4566 (recommended) and 4592 (deprecated)...
Starting mock Kinesis service in http ports 4566 (recommended) and 4568 (deprecated)...
Starting mock KMS service in http ports 4566 (recommended) and 4599 (deprecated)...
Starting mock Lambda service in http ports 4566 (recommended) and 4574 (deprecated)...
Starting mock CloudWatch Logs service in http ports 4566 (recommended) and 4586 (deprecated)...
Starting mock Redshift service in http ports 4566 (recommended) and 4577 (deprecated)...
Starting mock Route53 service in http ports 4566 (recommended) and 4580 (deprecated)...
Starting mock S3 service in http ports 4566 (recommended) and 4572 (deprecated)...
Starting mock Secrets Manager service in http ports 4566 (recommended) and 4584 (deprecated)...
Starting mock SES service in http ports 4566 (recommended) and 4579 (deprecated)...
Starting mock SNS service in http ports 4566 (recommended) and 4575 (deprecated)...
Starting mock SQS service in http ports 4566 (recommended) and 4576 (deprecated)...
Starting mock SSM service in http ports 4566 (recommended) and 4583 (deprecated)...
Starting mock Cloudwatch Events service in http ports 4566 (recommended) and 4587 (deprecated)...
Starting mock StepFunctions service in http ports 4566 (recommended) and 4585 (deprecated)...
Waiting for all LocalStack services to be ready
Waiting for all LocalStack services to be ready
Waiting for all LocalStack services to be ready
Waiting for all LocalStack services to be ready
Waiting for all LocalStack services to be ready
Waiting for all LocalStack services to be ready
Waiting for all LocalStack services to be ready
2020-05-18T16:56:24:WARNING:localstack.services.plugins: Service "dynamodb" not yet available, retrying...
Waiting for all LocalStack services to be ready
```

I tried below  possibilities , but still not able to start all the services.

```
python -m pip uninstall localstack
python -m pip install --no-cache --upgrade localstack
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
```

can anyone help me or point me to start the service without any problem.

Comment: did you get this resolved?

Comment: @AntarrByrd yes, it is resolve now.

Comment: @change198 How did you solve it? Thanks!

Comment: @DmitryAdonin where are stuck now, if  you want you can share me your docker compose.